# How to display Image (and Icon) on top of Image in CSS Grid cell.

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive grid with text and an icon on top of a picture in each grid cell. However, I can't seem to get the text to stack on top of the image.

Here is my current code:

https://codepen.io/FrazierChristie/pen/WgdEEx

```
<div id="igGrid">

<div class="ig1"> 
<img class="igImage" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1535/9821/products/3_1024x1024.jpg?v=1526628915" >
<div class="igText"> TEXT HERE  </div>
</div>

<div class="ig2"> 
 <img class="igImage" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1535/9821/products/grey9_1024x1024.jpg?v=1526628964" >
</div>

<div class="ig3"> 
 <img class="igImage" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1535/9821/products/12345_1024x1024.jpg?v=1526629035" >
</div>

<div class="ig4"> 
 <img class="igImage" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1535/9821/products/td1_1024x1024.jpg?v=1526628975" >
</div>

<div class="ig5"> 
 <img class="igImage" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1535/9821/products/grey6_1024x1024.jpg?v=1526629015" >
</div>

<div class="ig6"> 
<img class="igImage" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1535/9821/products/BlueLS3_1024x1024.jpg?v=1535724601" > 
    </div>

 <div class="ig7"> 
 <img class="igImage" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1535/9821/products/Leaf1_1024x1024.jpg?v=1526629035" >
  </div>

<div class="ig8"> 
<img class="igImage" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1535/9821/products/grey8_1024x1024.jpg?v=1526628964" >
</div>


<div class="ig9"> 
<img class="igImage" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1535/9821/products/td4_1024x1024.jpg?v=152662897" > 
</div>

<div class="ig10"> 
<img class="igImage" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1535/9821/products/grey4_1024x1024.jpg?v=1526628964" >  
</div>

<div class="ig11">  
<img class="igImage" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1535/9821/products/4a_1024x1024.jpg?v=1526628915">
 </div>

 </div>
```

and

```
#igGrid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#igGrid div{
  background: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
}

.ig1{
  grid-column: 1/2;

}

.ig2{
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.ig3{
  grid-column:3/5;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.ig4{
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2/4;
}

.ig9{
  grid-column: 3/5;
  grid-row: 4/6;
}

.igImage{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.igText{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  tranfrom: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Can anyone help at all?

Sorry about my formatting, I'm really new to all of this and just playing around really.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here try this.. Instead of calling the image out in your html, call it out on your css. all the grid is already formatted, you just need to enter the background:url() for every div class you created so for example...

```
HTML
<div class="ig1"> 
    <h2> Text Here </h2>
</div>

CSS
```

.ig1 {

```
background:url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1535/9821/products/3_1024x1024.jpg? 
v=1526628915');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
}
```

this way the img will be the background. so anything infront of the background will appear. I hope this helps!

try adding this to your css.

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and I just thought of a different way of doing this. you could try..
entering the img to be 100% of its container by typing this. and also add a z-index so that you can layer anything on top of it, so like your text.

```
img {
width: 100%;
z-index -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, that makes 100% sense, however I'm trying to add the code you suggested and it doesn't seem to be working. Having just changed the .ig1 CSS, ALL the images seem to have increased in size. I think perhaps because the image is much larger than the div which it is becoming the background for?

Comment: Ive just edited my answer. I hope that helps. just to clear things up. box-sizing: border-box will help to wrap your content within the borders. so hopefully your img will be contained in your grid cells. if not then try the other code I laid out for your default code

Comment: Neither seem to be working unfortunately @John. Hmm. The box-sizing: code doesn't seem to affect anything, as the images still display very large. The Z-index code doesn't make the text layer on top for some reason. Even if I set the text z-index: 1;.